# Python AttributeError: __enter__ from with self.request from imported library

Tags: python, api, network-programming, cisco

So I'm in network automation and testing a script written by someone else that relies on the dnacentersdk library -- that references the product called Cisco DNA Center if you're not familiar with it.  This is used for API calls to the product.  I've used pip to install the above library and it is of course imported into the main script. I've changed all variables from the script to point to my own in-house appliance and it connects fine, but won't complete.  The main script is long, which makes calls to the library above which are extremely long scripts, so I won't paste it all but when I run it, I get the following traceback and can't figure it out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "template_archive.py", line 201, in <module>
    archive_templates(dnac)
  File "template_archive.py", line 57, in archive_templates
    templates = dnac.template_programmer.gets_the_templates_available()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\dnacentersdk\api\v1_3_0\template_programmer.py", line 275, in gets_the_templates_available
    json=_payload)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\dnacentersdk\restsession.py", line 390, in get
    with self.request('GET', url, erc, 0, params=params, **kwargs) as resp:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

The portion of code from the restsession.py script it calls is here, remember that this script is part of the library -- not my own:

```
def get(self, url, params=None, **kwargs):
        """Sends a GET request.

        Args:
            url(basestring): The URL of the API endpoint.
            params(dict): The parameters for the HTTP GET request.
            **kwargs:
                erc(int): The expected (success) response code for the request.
                others: Passed on to the requests package.

        Raises:
            ApiError: If anything other than the expected response code is
                returned by the DNA Center API endpoint.

        """
        check_type(url, basestring, may_be_none=False)
        check_type(params, dict)

        # Expected response code
        erc = kwargs.pop('erc', EXPECTED_RESPONSE_CODE['GET'])
        stream = kwargs.get('stream', None)
        with self.request('GET', url, erc, 0, params=params, **kwargs) as resp:
            if stream and 'fileName' in resp.headers:
                try:
                    file_name = resp.headers.get('fileName')
                    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
                        logger.debug('Downloading {} ...'.format(file_name))
                        for chunk in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                            if chunk:
                                f.write(chunk)
                except Exception as e:
                    raise dnacentersdkException('DownloadFailure {}'.format(e))
                logger.debug('Downloaded')
            return extract_and_parse_json(resp, ignore=stream)
        return None
```

I have gone into the scripts of the library above and tried adding different print statements to figure out where it's breaking but I end up just getting the same output.  I may just need help understanding that exact portion of the code or maybe just how to troubleshoot it.  Appreciate any help here.  Thanks!

Comment: `self.request` is evidently not a context manager.

Comment: Can you help me understand that better?  I'm googling it to try to figure out how to troubleshoot this.  If it's not a context manager, then how would I go about fixing this?  I just wouldn't expect it to error on a script in the library.  Thanks!

Comment: Libraries often have bugs.  In addition installations often have issues.  Also the usage of the library maybe wrong. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/